# Customize Loopback explorer based on user access

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

From the docs I know I can disable or customize the routes in loopback explorer. I also know I can control the user access in the server using ACL, Roles, etc. But the explorer shows all the resources and methods available. Is it possible to customize loopback explorer to show only the methods that an user is able to access?

Answer (score 0):

> You can easily hide them by calling disableRemoteMethod() on the model

```
common/models/location.js
var isStatic = true;
MyModel.disableRemoteMethod('deleteById', isStatic);
```

Source: [Loopback docs](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Exposing+models+over+REST#ExposingmodelsoverREST-HidingmethodsandRESTendpoints)

Comment: Yes but is there a way to customize this depending on the users role in the model for example?? Or do i need to do this in a boot script or something like that?

Comment: I guess you can use checkaccessforcontext(), and disable it.